# CSS Best Practice/Newbie Question

Tags: css

Ok, a really quick question - which is the best way out of these to apply css styles:

1 - Use lots of different classes that apply different parts of the style i.e. class='font-1 red-bkg border-1' etc etc.

Or

2 - Style up individual parts of the site seperately

Comment: *Never* the first choice if the names are like `red-background border-1`.

Comment: One of the best practices on stackoverflow is to select an answer since all of these people spent time trying to help you.

Answer (score 2):

What you should do for `font` for example is to apple it to `body`, same for background colour, font colour etc...

```
body{font: Verdana 38px; color: #000; background: #fff;}
```

Then for individual features (e.g. margins, padding, borders etc) they should be defined in a per-class way.

```
.classname {
    margin: 0px 5px 10px 5px;
    padding: 10px 5px 10px 6px;
 }
```

It is better for maintainability and makes your HTML less messy.

I believe to justify shared classes you should have more than one property in it, otherwise you are not gaining anything from using CSS's modularity.

I.e. things like this are not good ideas:

```
.bold { font-weight: bold; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Style up individual parts of the site seperately. The other solution would kind of screw the intention behind it - separating content from styling.

Comment: My question with this technique is that, doesnt it make the site less flexible ?

Comment: @David this is correct. However, most elements of your site do not need to be more flexible that you'd achieve through that. Your site will most likely have unified headers/footers, navigation, and similar looking characteristics for the content. If you need good examples, just inspect the code of sites such as stackoverflow, w3.org or wordpress blogs.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you will enjoy this read, I certainly did:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/30-css-best-practices-for-beginners/

Comment: Good read, except the advice to use frameworks; I agree with [this guy](http://mondaybynoon.com/2007/08/27/please-do-not-use-css-frameworks/) that CSS is not something which can or should be framework'd.

Comment: good article.  a little out of date now... but when i read it i went down the list and learned some things that have streamlined everything.  make sure you get a full understanding of what the cascade in cascading style sheets really means before you get into too many specifics and then this list will really start to make sense.  it's often... "do i want to have to change 50 things later?  or 1."  and if you plan ahead... hopefully it will be 1 instead of 50.

Answer (score 0):

You should name logically classes, because when you change your layout and currently you have style like

```
.bold .5px-brd .red.bg
```

then changing this to another colour and style will include grep'ing through entire application code in order to correct css styles.

As you may notice approach like

```
.bold .5px-brd .red.bg
```

it's good, and don't go with philosophy of CSS.

Classes with name like
    .bold 
should be used as auxiliary style. Never as basic construction block.

Comment: Classes with names like `.bold` should *never* be used, even as auxiliary styles. Instead, ask yourself *why* the thing is bold and pick a class name based on that. `<span class="bestvalue">` ... `<div class="popular">` etc. Many things serve as headings, so use `H<n>` headings-plus-CSS rather than div-plus-CSS where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/RMfEn/

### html

```
<section class='container blocks'>
    <h2>Blocks of content</h2>
    <div class='block highlight-theme'>
        <p>None of the styling should be done in the html.</p>
    </div>
        
    <div class='block base-theme'>
        <p>You can use modular classes to style common pieces of the layout and then modify them with more specific classes.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class='block contrast-theme'>
       <p>So the stuff in this box could be a dark-theme with .contrast-theme or something</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

## css

```
.container, .block { /* structural elements */
    width: 100%;
    float; left;
    padding: .5rem;
    overflow: hidden; /* use a clear-fix instead */
}

/* mini themes /// mix and match */

.base-theme {
    background: lightgray;
    color: black;
}

.highlight-theme {
    background: yellow;
    color: red;
}

.contrast-theme {
    background: gray;
    color: white;
}
```